# Pivot table to return the FIRST value in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Glad to be joining the forum.

My question deals with attempting to return the FIRST value that occurs over several columns of data, using a pivot table that is filtered within a narrow time range. My current pivot table works by counting values in each column over the time rows. However I'm really only interested in the FIRST value that I come across for each person. So the raw looks something like this:

```
Person|TimeValue|Variable1|Variable2
1     |     1   | 1       |   0    
1     |     2   | 1       |   0    
2     |     1   | 1       |   0    
2     |     2   | 0       |   1
```

What I currently get for a pivot using a range of time1 to time 2 is

```
1     |         |2        |   0
2     |         |1        |   1
```

Clearly, the time range I select includes MULTIPLE values in the same column, leading to counts of >1. What I'm thinking is that there is a way to use the same time sorting, but count only the FIRST time a value occurs in that variable, so that the pivot reports only the first time a value occurs within the range for the variables of interest.

Is there a simple way, or am I going to have to do this in VBA?

Much appreciated for any and all help. This is my first more complicated attempt with the newer pivots.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the problem you would want to solve using a pivot table. You could just use the `VLOOKUP` Excel function to solve this issue in a simple way. `VLOOKUP` will always return the first value in the lookup range that matches the lookup value.